# How to change and reload application configuration using a jax-rs service

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have to provide the user of my application, a resource end point with which he should be able to configure the application properties. The property class should be singleton. How can I achieve this. I am using springboot.

What I tried:
I did some reading on actuators, but it seems to work on application.properties,
but I need to use a rest service to configure the properties.

Comment: Have you tried this https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config?

Comment: Thank you so much...Got the answers in the link that you shared. However, I used a simple web service to configure the user related properties and transfer it to a singleton property.